# Create python Dictionary from table

Tags: python

I have a for loop to go through 500k records in a table, and can obtain a bunch of values from each record.
I would like to create a dictionary from this, which I then use to update a separate table.
Not sure how this can be achieved.

Comment: is it a SQL table? You can use Pandas to read the data directly from SQL table and then process it and push the processed data in the new table.

Comment: Please clarify: what is the `table` in your case. Is it a python datastructure, database table, pandas dataframe, html table?

Comment: You see, your question right now is extremely broad. Give us a sample of your table, as well as one of the dictionary you want and, if possible, your coding attempts. With more details, we can proper assist you :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing list to dict can be achieved by something like this:

```
>>> a = [('key', 'val'), ('key2', 'val2')]
>>> dict(a)
{'key': 'val', 'key2': 'val2'}
```

Or if you really want to use `for` loop:

```
>>> a = [('key', 'val'), ('key2', 'val2')]
>>> d={}
>>> for e in a:
...  d[e[0]] = e[1]
... 
>>> d
{'key': 'val', 'key2': 'val2'}
```

Code after discussion in comments below

```py
d = {}
for [...]:
  # I'm assuming there are PropNo, Pipe_ID, XCoord, YCoord, NewDMA variables
  d[PropNo] = (PiPe_ID, XCoord, YCoord, NewDMA)

# Then when you want to get XCoord of Prop with PropNo=37
print(d[37][1])
```

Comment: thanks. yes the data is an SQL Server table. It contains the coordinates of points, which I need to use to update the geometry of a separate table

Comment: @user3050151 but can you export it to a list? if not, you can try to give us some examples of your data you are trying to handle

Comment: PropNo, Pipe_ID, XCoord, YCoord, NewDMA are the fields I need to write to a dictionary. There are 500k records. I then update another table and use the coordinates fields to update the geometry of the new table using ESRI modules. Will 500K cause memory issue with these 5 fields?

Comment: I think they shouldn't... Python is a powerful tool.

Comment: Great. I'll try this. So I have going back to my original question. for row in cursor prop = row[0], pipe=row[1], x=row[2], y=row[3] , dma=row[4]. Whats the most efficient way to store all the field values? using a dictionary?

Comment: A tuple will be better. It's faster a lot.
A tuple is `(prop, pipe, x, y, dma)`.
A list is `[prop, pipe, x, y, dma]`.
And this tuple in dict of course, so `{key: (prop, pipe, x, y, dma)}`

Comment: If you want to use PropNo as a key, use `a = {prop: (pipe, x, y, dma), prop2: (pipe2, x2, y2, dma2)}`. Then when you want to get some value: `a[PropNo][0]` for pipe, `...[1]` for x `...[2]` for y and `...[3]` for dma.

Comment: how do I go about creating the tuple in the for loop?

Comment: Can I help you with anything else?